# How to Fill data to data grid in Button command wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a application following WPF MVVM pattern, There I need to fill a datagrid with data when button click event. So My view model related to grid also get filled with data but it doesn't appear in the grid in screen. What I have done wrong here? Any advice will be much appreciated.

Author-Model Class

```
public class Author
    {
        private int id;
        private string name;
        private string bookTitle;
        private bool isMVP;
        public Author(int ID, string Name, string BookTitle, bool IsMVP)
        {
            this.id = ID;
            this.name = Name;
            this.bookTitle = BookTitle;
            this.isMVP = IsMVP;
        }
        public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        public string BookTitle
        {
            get { return bookTitle; }
            set { bookTitle = value; }
        }
        public bool IsMVP
        {
            get { return isMVP; }
            set { isMVP = value; }
        }
    }
```

AuthorViewModel

```
public class AuthorViewModel: ObservableCollection<Author>
    {
        public AuthorViewModel():base()
        {
            Add(new Author
            (
                1,
            "Cather",
                 "Graphics Programming",
                true
            ));
           Add(new Author
            (
              2,
                "Mathew Cochran",
                 "LINQ in Vista",
                 true
            ));
            Add(new Author
            (
                 3,
                 "Mike Gold",
                 "Programming in Vista",
                true
            ));

        }
    }
```

MainWindowViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ICommand LoadGridCommand { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            LoadGridCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadGrid,null);
        }

        private void LoadGrid(object parameter)
        {
            AuthorViewModel authorVM = new AuthorViewModel();

        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CustomCtrldemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomCtrldemo"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CustomCtrldemo.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowVM"/>
        <vm:AuthorViewModel x:Key="AuthorVM"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowVM }}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="TxtFilterGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="20"  />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Load Grid"  Width="100" Height="20" Command="{Binding LoadGridCommand}" />
        <Grid x:Name="gridAuthors" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AuthorVM} }" >
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgAuthors"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Book Title" Binding="{Binding  Path=BookTitle}" />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="MVP Enabled" Binding="{Binding  Path=IsMVP}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Load Control"  Width="100" Height="20"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Set Content"  Width="100" Height="20"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtbox1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="20" />
        <TextBox Name="txtUniqueId" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="20"/>
        <local:LoadControl />
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="center" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" >
            <Button Content="OK"  Width="100" Height="20"/>

            <Button  Content="Cancel"  Width="100" Height="20"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have never used the `{StaticResource ...}` part before. Where did you get that? Normally you just do `DataContext = {Binding <PropertyName>}`. Also you can normally see in the output window, if some bindings are failing.

Comment: Instantiating viewmodels in `XAML` is not a good practice. You can't use dependency injection also. And What is missing here you forget to bind `DataGrid`s `ItemsSource` property.

Comment: @Noceo Static Resource is using because of                                <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowVM"/>
        <vm:AuthorViewModel x:Key="AuthorVM"/>
    </Window.Resources>                                                                                             this part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your separate `AuthorViewModel` doesn't make sense. You should instead have a `Authors` property in the main view model:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ICommand LoadGridCommand { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<Author> Authors { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Author>();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        LoadGridCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadGrid, null);
    }

    private void LoadGrid(object parameter)
    {
        // Authors.Clear();
        // Authors.Add(...);
    }
}
```

You should assign an instance of the main view model to the window's DataContext and bind like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Authors}" ...>
```

Comment: Thank You for the solution. It solved my problem. :) @Clemens

Comment: And I am confused with this syntax what does it really mean?                            public ObservableCollection<Author> Authors { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Author>();

Comment: It declares and initializes a readonly property, as well as `public ICommand LoadGridCommand { get; }` declares a readonly property.